# iTunes integration & resizing

Tags: c#, itunes, taglib, naudio, itunes-app

I am building an itunes add on. One of the specification is to make sure that the add in starts up as itunes starts and re-size itunes in a way that the two applications will be visible to the user. This has already been implemented by the popular itunes add in called Music tune up (http://www.tuneupmedia.com/). Ideally, my application would mimic musicTuneUp and, when loaded, it would look like [this image](http://imageshack.us/f/443/tuneupattachedtotheside.jpg/) 
Does any one knows how I could do this. I am implementing my application in C# windows form.